# GMail option missing from share sheet on iOS

Tags: sharing

I'm running iOS 14 and use both Mail.app and Gmail (personal and work respectively). From the share sheet I see Mail but not Gmail. I suspect it's because Mail is my default mail app. Is there a way to force both Mail and GMail to appear as options on the share sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it seems obvious, but did you try rebooting your device?

Comment: Just checked on iOS 15.2.1 and I do now see the Gmail icon in the share sheet from Mobile Safari (for example). So could have just been a iOS cache issue (or even a iOS 14 bug). Thanks for waking this up.